# nomad shows job as dead

Tags: nomad

I am new to nomad. We are using nomad in production along with docker, consul, vault, ansible. When I run a nomad job from my local machine, Job registers successfully but show status as dead.

```
Roadrunner-2:nomad Shailesh$ nomad run -detach -address=http://nomad.example-private.com:4646 production/router.hcl 
Job registration successful
Evaluation ID: c9e77cb5-ef69-1c63-e926-f131b331d800
```

When I do nomad status

```
Roadrunner-2:nomad Shailesh$ nomad status
ID        Type     Priority  Status
metrics   system   50        running
registry  service  50        running
router    system   50        dead
```

And particularly when I check status of the job it gives error.

```
Roadrunner-2:nomad Shailesh$ nomad status router
ID          = router
Name        = router
Type        = system
Priority    = 50
Datacenters = us-east-1
Status      = dead
Periodic    = false
Error querying job summary: Unexpected response code: 404 (job not found)
```

I would highly appreciate any direction for troubleshooting above.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to verify whether your job is successful?
$nomad eval-status c9e77cb5-ef69-1c63-e926-f131b331d800(your_eval_id)

Comment: `nomad eval-status c9e77cb5-ef69-1c63-e926-f131b331d800` shows
`ID                 = c9e77cb5`
`Status             = complete`
`Status Description = complete`
`Type               = service`
`TriggeredBy        = job-register`
`Job ID             = cloudwatch`
`Priority           = 50`
`Placement Failures = false`

Comment: eval-status output shows that job is of type 'service' scheduler but nomad status shows it is of type 'system'. Do you have router.hcl contents posted somewhere?

Comment: My mistake I gave the eval status of cloudwatch job. Below is the correct one for router job.

`nomad eval-status c9d983cc-63b3-b95d-d09f-c35be2b461cb`

`ID                 = c9d983cc
Status             = complete
Status Description = complete
Type               = system
TriggeredBy        = job-register
Job ID             = router
Priority           = 50
Placement Failures = false`

Comment: You could also try "nomad status -verbose -eval router"

Comment: `nomad status -verbose -eval router` doesn't work for me.

Comment: sorry thats a typo. it is -evals . Also check whether you are able to run that docker image independently. Sometime docker container exits when you have a foreground Job as ENTRYPOINT or CMD. I'm not sure about what your job specification is and why it is causing problems.

Comment: Make sure you have same version of nomad running in server and nodes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46757/discussion-between-shailesh-sutar-and-chandru-ops).